# Lock Mutex but don't wait for it to be unlocked

Tags: c++11, concurrency, thread-safety, mutex, boost-mutex

How would I lock a `std::mutex` or `boost::mutex` so at the start of my method I would lock it, but regardless of it already being locked or not just proceed with the code.

I want this kind of behaviour because there is going to be 2 threads that'll be reading and writing to an `std::map`. When it's reading I just want to lock the mutex so that it can continue reading but the writing stops. When it's writing I want it to lock another mutex, which'll block reading and writing, and wait for both mutexes to be unlocked so that it can work with the map alone.

Comment: Sounds more like a job for `shared_mutex`, tbh.

Comment: @Xeo Indeed. If you want you can put that up as an answer and I'll approve it. If not I'll put it up.

Comment: Use boost:shared_mutex (readers-writer lock). C++14 will implement std::shared mutex (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Shared_mutexes_and_locking)